# Maven and dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven

I cannot quite understand what we need maven for and what dependency is.

Could anyone explain in simple words what  means? Where does it look for them?
When writing:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It tells:

```
Missing artifact org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.0.0
```

What does it mean?

I have  2 versions of maven installed on my system - one for the cmd, the second one as a plugin for eclipse. What is the difference? Which way is it more common to use Maven - from the cmd or from eclipse? 
And I read somewhere that maven needs connection to the internet - what is that for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are newbie to Maven, I would suggest you to go through the following links

[What is Maven?](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html)

[DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-mavenv2/)

[Article in Java World](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/03/29/maven-2-0.html)

[More Maven articles](http://maven.apache.org/articles.html)

Comment: Your answer is too broad. It is better to answer precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is a build tool (like ant) which can pull specific versions of libraries and other dependencies from an online server. If you want to use methods which are in a library (even an older version of it) you don't need to install the library on your computer, maven will grab the specified version and store it for you. You can even have two projects which use two different versions of the same library and not have any conflicts, as maven will handle all the libraries for you.

The code you have specifies that you will be using version 2.0.0 of the eclipselink library. Maven will search for that version of that library, first in its cache of libraries and then in the online database, and compile your code along with the library, so your classes have access to the library methods.

I don't think either the command line or eclipse plugin are more popular - I use mostly command line but have both installed.

Answer (score 0):

As to why maven is indicating that your dependencies is missing, you can use http://mvnrepository.com to find dependencies in the maven central repository. Searching for "org.eclipse.persistence" reveals that might actually be needing:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```